# Why is this sentence grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I was reading one of Olivia Rodrigo's [interviews](https://www.goodmorningamerica.com/culture/story/olivia-rodrigo-talks-sudden-success-drivers-license-strange-75468691):

> I say, ‘I've never felt this way for no one' which is completely grammatically incorrect.

Why is that incorrect? It is a part of her song, Driver's license, lyrics.

Comment: Technically speaking, it's invalid because of the "double negative" *(**never** + **no-one**)*, which should be *I've **never** felt this way for **anyone**.* But in practice it's not uncommon in colloquial conversational contexts, and the syntax of song lyrics isn't a usually a suitable subject for this site anyway.

Comment: Why did you leave out the part of the sentence that explained "I also put a **double negative** in the song when I say,…” Do you not know that a double negative is typically viewed as ungrammatical?

Comment: @ColleenV Well, I wasn't familiar with the double negative; hence I thought that's not important.

Comment: If you didn’t know what a double negative was, why didn’t you look it up so you could understand the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Olivia was referring to the double negative, *never* and *no*.  She said

> "I also put a double negative in the song when I say, ‘I've never felt this way for no one,' which is completely grammatically incorrect.

Double negative is defined as the use of two negatives in the same phrase or sentence.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-negative)